# executing async task or background task in a Django service running on GCP Cloud run

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-tasks

I'm building a Django application and planning to deploy it on Cloud Run. I have used celery before, but it seems too complicated to set it up with Cloud Run.

After some exploration, I found Cloud Task and Cloud Scheduler. My understanding is I can use Cloud Scheduler to init HTTP requests to my cloud run service periodically and use Cloud Task as a queue to send HTTP requests on demand.

So my question is what's the best practice to deploy my service? For the easiness of development, I see I can only have one Django repo docker and deploy that to a single cloud run service. Then all the regular requests and all async/background requests will go to the same service(the task execute endpoints will also be public). Another way is to deploy a second cloud run service using the same docker, but hide that in vpc network. Is there a good reason to do the second one instead? (If cloud run scales itself, isn't that cost the same?)

I looked at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service, There is service to service authentication, but wonder did anyone implemented the Django level permission auth on task endpoints? can i use my service jwt instead for that?

hope anyone with previous experience on that can shed some light.

Comment: Architecture is a matter of choice. if you choose to have, on the same instance, the realtime and the async processing, you can, it's "monolith" and you need a always on and no scale out platform for that. Compute engine (or GKE) is the best place. If you want to scale independently the realtime app and the background task (one is based on the number of request, the other on the CPU usage), it's a multi/micro service architecture and Cloud Run (+Cloud Task/PubSub) is the right choice. But if you try to bend the model and to put a monolith on CLoud Run, you will have issue

Comment: From the above conversation, I believe your issue is resolved. Can you post your solution as answer?